# JSP calculating variables

Tags: jsp

I have this statement in JSP

```
<s:property value="(planVo.description).substring(0, 30)" />
```

that someone already wrote. But this does not properly work, for example, if the length of planVo.description is more than 30, it works otherwise there is black.

I am trying to implement some IF condition like this:

```
if(planVo.description.length()<= 30) {
    value = planVo.description;
}

else {
    value = planVo.description.substring(0, 30);
}
```

But my problem is the variable value "planVo.description" is not accessible from anywhere.
This is only accessible from the tag

I do not have experience in JSP but I need to fix this issue, how do I perform this IF ELSE condition outside the s:property tag?

Answer (score 0):

can you tell taglib location of "s"

if it is jstl tag than you can use

or if it is spring tag  you can get this data in scriptlet  using request.getAttribute("planVo");